# System design: whether to normalize the departments or not

Tags: database, salesforce, normalization

I'm working with two consultants in one project. The thing is we reached a point where both of them cannot get into an agreement and each offer a different approach.

The thing is we have a store with four departments and we want to find the best approach for working with all of them in the same database.

Each department sell different products: Cars, Boats, Jetskies and Motorbikes.

When the data is inserted or updated in each department there are some triggers to be fires so different workflows will begin, when adding a new car there are certain requirements that needs to be checked as well as the details of the car that are completely different than a boat. Also, regarding the data there are not many fields there are in common, I would say so far only the brand, color, model and year, everything else is specific for each deparment due to the different products and how they work with them..

Consultant one says:

- Create one table for all the departments and use a column to identify what department the row belongs to, this way you will have only one trigger and inside the trigger you will then call the function/mehod you need for each record type.
- Reason: you only have one table (with over 200 fields) and one trigger, is easier to maintain. Also if you need to report you just need to query one table and filter based on the record type. If you need to report for all the items you don't need to have multiple joins.

Consultant two says:

- Create one table for each deparment and a trigger for each table.
- Reason: you will have smaller tables (aprox 50 fields each) and is more flexible and you have it all separated. If you want to report you need to join the tables as you want to include data from different places.

I see the advantages of having everything in one place but if I want to expand or change anything I have the feeling I will bre creating a beast table as the data grows.

On the other side keep it separated look more appealing but will need to setup everything for each different table.

What would you say is the best approach?

Comment: Does one department deal with more than one Product?

Comment: If you consider there are multiple types, brands and models of cars, boats, jetskies and motorcicles I would say yes. i.e. for cars you have suv, truck, sedan, van, coupe, wagon, convertibl, crossover, etc... And then the engine, awd, atc...

Comment: I also don't know what your doing exactly but couldn't these be pricebooks?

Comment: Google my comments re googling/searching re database/sql subtypes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably listen to consultant number two.

The thing is, all design is trade-offs.  You need to assess the pros and cons of each approach and you need to think about the risks that each design entails.

- What happens when your design grows?  (department 5, more details per product type,...)
- What happens when the system scales up to higher transaction volumes?
- What happens when your business rules change?

I've been doing this for a long time and I've seen some pendulums swing back and forth when it comes to what is "in fashion" as far as database and software best practices.

I'd say right now the prevailing wisdom is that **separation of concerns** is innately good.  This means you should keep your program logic (trigger code) separate for each department.  This makes sense because your logic will vary from one product type to the next since they mostly have distinct columns.

This second point is also important, because your stake in the ground for a transactional system should always be start with third normal form (or higher, if necessary).  Sometimes you can get away without it, but four different types of objects with 40 or more distinct attributes each doesn't sound like a good candidate for jamming everything into one table.  How do you keep track of which columns belong to which type of product, for example?  A separate table for each product type keeps this clean and simple - and importantly - easy for your support programmers to understand.

Contrary to what consultant one is saying, having one trigger instead of four is not likely to be easier to maintain if that one trigger is a big bowl of spaghetti, or even four tidy, well written subroutines joined together with a `switch` type statement.

These days, programmers favour short, atomic, single-purpose functions (triggers, in your case).

If there is enough common data and common business logic that doing it four times seems awkward, then maybe you have a good candidate for a super-type / sub-type design.

Answer (score 0):

I'll say one

These are all Products, It doesn't matter that its a Bike or a Car.  You can control the fields and the object by RecordTypes and Page layouts and that will save you from having 4 Objects, which means potentially 8 new classes(if it follows my pattern it could be up to 20+) + all of the workflow rules and validation rules across the these new objects, it will be very hard to maintain a structure that has 4 objects but are all the same thing.. Tracking Products.

Down the road if you decide to add a new product such as planes, it will be very easy to add a plane to this object and the code will be able to pick up from there if needed.  You will definitely need Record Types to manage each Product.  The trigger code shouldn't be an issue if the consultants are building it properly meaning a trigger should never have any business logic so as long as that is followed all of the code will be maintainable

Comment: You made a very good point @EricSSH. Let's say my company grows and we decide to start selling trucks, we will then need to add 40 more fields to the Products table/object and add another condition into the trigger. So far so good. But, as we are talking right now, we are thinking about selling planes, I will then need to add 200 fields for one engine cetna type planes alone... Now I'm over 500 fields! What do I do now?

Comment: I think you should be asking why does each product need 50 fields?

Comment: How could you store the information for each vehicle in the inventory? I mean, I have a car in inventory I need to include to model, year, maker, engine type, number of doors, awd, leather interior, cd, mp3, fuel type, etc... same for all the other items in the inventory: boats, jetskies and motorcycles.

Comment: Fields shouldn't be created as Car Door, just doors, car interior is just interior, and car engine is just engine and so on.  You shouldn't think how do I maintain 4 different products today how do I maintain products

Comment: Yeah, I completely agree, and if you see my comment I never used "car doors" or "car interior", I just used "door" and interior. there are fields that can be common, but the interior type and values and information between a boat and a car is not the same, mostly when you start including "kitchen type", bathroom, water pump (yeah boats have kitchens and bathrooms), etc... and unfortunately we are not talking about a small number of fields, otherwise I think we wouldn't be facing this problem.

Comment: On my phone so typos.. Yeah it's tough,  maybe you need 1 car object with a master detail to product, I just can't get passed that these are products not cars, boats.. could you be using pricebooks? Also you should post this in Salesforce stack, you will get better answers for sfdc architecture

Answer (score 0):

I will go with **one**.

I assume you have a large number of products and this list will grow in future. All these are Products at the end. They will have some common fields and common logic.

If you use Process Builder with Invocable classes instead of Triggers, you may be able to get away with just configuration changes while adding a new object, if its fields and functionality are same/similar to a existing object.

There may also be limitation on the number of different objects a profile has access to based on your license types.

Salesforce has a standard object called Product. Its a single object to be classifies based on record type.

I would have gone with approach two if this was not salesforce. Based on how salesforce works and the limitations it imposes one seems like a better and cleaner solution.

Comment: As I said in the question they only have 4 common fields, that is ~2% of the total number of fields. If I keep adding products I keep adding fields as each products has unique characteristics and Salesforce has some limitations regarding the number of fields I can have in an object. How can you control what field belong to what product? Shall I need to always go and double check into the layouts? What happens when I have 500 fields? (Same as commented in @EricSSH answer).

Comment: Hmmm, looking at all the comments, I think a single level object structure will not work for you. You can have a object called Product and then have child object called Product attribute. So we will have a Product Car which will have child objects Door and Interior. This is a unstructured approach.

Comment: Alternative is to have a Product object and then a Engine Object and a Door object, etc. You can then have a junction object that links a Product to a Door or Engine. This is assuming that different Cars models (Products) can have same Engine.

Answer (score 0):

I would say **option 2**.

Why?

(1) I would find one table with 200+ columns harder to maintain. You're also then going to have to expose fields for an object that doesn't need said fields.

(2) You are also going to have to "hide" logic inside the trigger which then decides to do different actions based on the type of department etc...

(3) Option 2 involves more "scaffolding" and separate objects but those are objects are inherently smaller and easier to maintain and don't specifically hide logic or cause any sort of ambiguity.

(4) Option 2 abides by the single responsibility principle. Not everyone follows this I understand but I find it a good guiding principle, as the responsibility for the data lies with the individual table and the responsibility for triggered the action lies with the individual trigger as opposed to just being one mammoth entity/trigger.

** I would state that I am simply looking at this from a software development perspective, I am not sure whether or not SalesForce would handle this setup, but it is the way I would personally prefer to design it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Option 2 for me.

You've said that there is little common data and the trigger logic is completely different. Here are some additional technical considerations.

**Option 1 Warnings**

- The trigger would be a single point of failure and errors will be trickier to debug. I have worked with large triggers where broken logic near the top has stopped logic near the bottom from running, sometimes silently! You also have to maintain conditional guards to control the flow of logic based on the data which is another opportunity for error.
- I'm not red hot on indexes but I believe performance will suffer due to no natural order of the multi-purpose data. More specific tables will yield better indexing strategies. Also, large rows can lead to fragmented indexes.

  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pamitt/2010/12/23/notes-sql-server-index-fragmentation-types-and-solutions/
- You would need extra consideration when setting nullable/default constraints on each surplus field not relevant to the product in question. These subtleties can introduce bugs and might make it harder if/when you decide to work with a data layer technology such as Entity Framework. E.g. the logical difference between NULL, 0 and 'None', especially on shared columns.